# How to properly start a web app project in IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.5 with tomcat?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea, tomcat, jersey

I want to start a web app in IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.5 with Tomcat to build Rest Api's with Jersey and Hibernate. How can i setup this properly

I tried setting it up with just a plain project but it doesn't seem to work. When i look at examples the pom.xml file looks different then what i have.

Comment: This question looks interesting. I would like to know myself. Do you have the community edition of IntelliJ or did you pay for it? What manuals did find yourself on how to do this? Can you cite a manual and make clear what question remains after reading it?